# Gedmo Timestampable Annotation Doesn't Appear to Work With Event Listeners

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So,

I have an Entity set up with Timestampable fields, like so:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Bundle\Entity;

use Acme\PathEnumerableInterface as EnumerableInterface;
use Acme\PathEnumerable as PathEnumerableTrait;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * SomeEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class SomeEntity implements EnumerableInterface
{
    use PathEnumerableTrait;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    private $updatedAt;


    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }
}
```

I have then set up a lifecycle subscriber for postPersist, postUpdate, and postFlush events. The service.yml looks like this:

```
services:
    acme.element_listener:
        class: %iacme.element_listener.class%
        arguments:
            manager: "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

The actual listener looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\EventListener;

use Acme\PathEnumerableInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;

class EventListener
{
    /**
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $paths = [];

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return ['postPersist'];
    }

    private function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        // Set $newPath to a generated path and check so we don't end up in an infinite loop
        if ($entity->getPath() != $newPath) {
            //... Do some stuff with the entity
            $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

When I remove the event listener, everything is fine and the timestampable fields are filled in correctly. However, when I create a new entity with the listener enabled timestampable fields aren't filled out.

My question is, then, what would cause the event listener to stop Gedmo filling in the timestampable fields? I'm probably doing something really silly, but as yet I can't see what that might be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there were a couple of things wrong here that were causing me issues:

1. My EventListener Class didn't implement EventSubscriber. The class *should* have been declared like so:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Acme\Bundle\EventListener;

   use Acme\PathEnumerableInterface;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;
   use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;

   class EventListener implements EventSubscriber
   {
       // .....
   }
   ```
2. You can't pass the EntityManager as a construct argument. This actually makes quite a bit of sense when you think about it, and doesn't really hinder what I do as the getEntityManager event is available in the LifecycleEventArgs object and the PostFlushEventArgs object